# ToolTip ignores specified DateTime format specifier

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, tooltip, format-specifiers

I'm struggling with a strange issue regarding `ToolTip`s in WPF:

First, the code:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat='{}{0:g}'}"
           ToolTip="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat='{}{0:f}'}" />
```

As you can see, the "[g format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Anchor_5)" (e. g. `2016-12-24 23:42`) is used for the timestamp's display and "[f format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Anchor_3)" (e. g. `Saturday, 24. December 2016 23:42`) for its `ToolTip`.

However, what I get is: `2016-12-24 23:42`. In other words: the `ToolTip` shows exactly the same format as does the `TextBlock`.

It gets even weirder when switching the `TextBlock` to the "f format specifier", too: the `ToolTip` just stays in the format specified by the "g format specifier".

So, I've got two questions:
**a) Why is that?**
and
**b) How to enforce my desired format?**

Comment: I'm _not_ familiar with WPF but I have a few question: **1)** Since these are standard formats, isn't `StringFormat=g` and `StringFormat=g` enough? **2)** Can't you use custom date and time formats instead like `StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` and `StringFormat=dddd, dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm`? **3)** The culture use for formatting is not `sq-AL` isn't it? Since `g` and `f` format specifiers generates the same result since this culture has the _same_ value for `LongDatePattern` and `ShortDatePattern` properties.

Comment: Regarding your questions: **1)**: No, as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx). **2)**: I don't want to custom hard-code something that's already built into .NET. **3)**: No, it's not. There are, however, several other `Culture`s used, e. g. `de-DE`. But most importantly: `f`and `g` result in **different** outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat={}{0:g}}">
  <TextBlock.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:f}" />
  </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

As Tooltip can contain anything, we should use its ContentStringFormat.

Comment: Thanks for your second suggestion. Specifying it in detail via `ContentStringFormat` does indeed change the displayed format. But it doesn't answer the question as to why it shortens the format.

Comment: As Tooltip can contain anything, any object, internally it has a simple converter ToString, and that ignores the StringFormat defined in DataBinding. That's why Tooltip has a ContentStringFormat

Comment: Thanks for the insights. That's almost all I was looking for. Last thing: there's no chance to keep it a one-liner, e.g. use `ContentStringFormat` within the `ToolTip` attribute instead of inline definition (Please, correct me, if that's not the right technical term form for `<TextBlock.ToolTip> ... </TextBlock.ToolTip>`!)?

Comment: Hi. There is no way to use like: "<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat={}{0:g}}" Tooltip="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp}" Tooltip.ContentStringFormat="{}{0:f}" />   If you wanna use in one line only, I believe you should change approach: create another readonly property in your ViewModel retuning your Timestamp value formatted as you want and bind this new property to Tooltip.

Comment: It's a pitty that there's no attached property available. Anyway, you've answered all questions to the full extend - I therefore happily accept your second answer! Once again, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax is not correct.

See:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat={}{0:g}}"
           ToolTip="{Binding SelectedItem.Approver.Timestamp, StringFormat={}{0:f}}" />
```

Comment: No, it's not as it's valid to encapsulate such parameters in single quotes. However, being eager to try suggestions, I tried it without the single quotes. Unfortunately, the result remains the same. :(